# Does my ANOVA table make sense?

Tags: regression, anova

these are my results as part of my Master Thesis.
I am curious whether the high degree of freedom for the residuals of 98 makes sense at all. My data set has n=100 observation and I have 1 independent variable.

Thank you!

ﬁ[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is totally self-consistent.

You get the one degree of freedom by having one dimension in your feature space (from the one predictor), often denoted as $p-1$ where $p$ is the number of parameters in your model (including the intercept, then subtract the one intercept parameter).

You get $98$ from the sample size minus the number of parameters in the model.

Note that, if you have a categorical $x$ variable, your hypothesis test is equivalent to an equal-variance (not Welch) t-test of $y$ values in the two categories.

Comment: Hi Dave, thank you so much for your feedback.
Also, I appreciate the heads up regarding the hypothesis test. I use categorical data indeed. I will look further into the equal-variance t-test. Thanks!

Comment: Now I am a bit worried whether I used the right method. Is it still valid to utilize the anova for my case?

Comment: ANOVA uses categorical $x$ variables. Do you mean a categorical $y$ variable?

Comment: I am using a categorical x variable!

Comment: @Sammy Then what you did seems reasonable. What is your concern?

Comment: Perfect thank you! 
In two of my other analyses, I am using one time values from 1-4 and for the other one 1-3 as the y variable.
1-4 are cardinal values, however 1-3 are the levels and of ordinal nature. I did an anova with both of these data sets. Does that also sound self-consistent to you?

Comment: I am not following. Perhaps you can flesh out the details in a new question.

Comment: sure! thank you for trying to help.
Analysis 1: x is a categorical variable, y is not. 
Analysis 2: x is a categorical variable, y is also categorical.

Comment: Please post as a new question. Unlike much of the internet, Cross Validated is strictly Q&A, not a discussion board.